# Docker CE not available for Fedora 32?

Tags: docker

How to resolve this issue?

````
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'docker-ce-stable':
  - Status code: 404 for https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/32/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 13.226.68.18)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'docker-ce-stable': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Ignoring repositories: docker-ce-stable```
````

Answer (score 5):

If you want a specific older version of Docker CE, then you should just give up and use their F31 repo. If you just want "Docker CE" the [upstream code](https://mobyproject.org/) on which it is based is already included in Fedora 32.

```
dnf install moby-engine
```

If you've upgraded from Fedora 31 or lower to 32 and need to switch from Docker CE to upstream moby, just do:

```
rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
dnf --allowerasing swap docker-ce moby-engine
```

There's a [longer tutorial](https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/) in Fedora Magazine along with a GitHub issue for [Fedora 32 support in Docker](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/955).

Answer (score 2):

as of today (June 13th 2020) the appears to be no docker for fedora 32. Take a look at the OS requirements:

To install Docker Engine, you need the 64-bit version of one of these Fedora versions:

```
Fedora 30
Fedora 31
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/fedora/

And that explains why you get a 404 (not found) when trying to get the fedora 32 docker, it just is not there.

Some people are using the f31 repo and it seems to work, you create a file /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo

```
[docker-ce-stable]
name=Docker CE Stable - \$basearch
baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/31/\$basearch/stable
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/gpg
```

and install docker-ce as you would according to the instructions on the documentation.

Comment: thanks @natxo, I read through convenience script and decided to wait for docker-ce for Fedora32.

Comment: Please note you need to remove the backslashes in this snippet.
(I assume this comes from a shell script, where escaping `$` is necessary)